# Are there any file explorers with third-party net drives supported on Windows?

Tags: windows, file-management

I would like to use Solid Explorer on Android as an example. I can add FTP sites, my Google Drive, OneDrive, Dropbox and so on with OAuth in Solid Explorer, so that it puts all of my net drives together. I am not meaning adding a "Google Drive" item to the side bar of Windows' explorer. I am wondering if there are any applications on Windows that works like Solid Explorer.

Comment: How about an extension that makes Google Drive/etc appear as normal disks inside Windows Explorer?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul It should also meet my need, but I haven't find one yet. Any recommendation?